# For days I've marveled at the silhouettes, until I realized they had color (Winter/Summer Bash 2022)

Tags: bug, design, winter-bash, winter-bash-2022

Using Firefox 108.0 since the start of the Bash, my [Winter/Summer Bash site](https://winterbash2022.stackexchange.com/) looked like this:

[image: Silhouettes image]

I pondered why they were just silhouettes, but I didn't investigate. I assumed this was by design. While visiting a friend, I viewed it on my iPhone 14 Pro Max using iOS 16.1.2 to notice some have color and others are my silhouettes:

[image: first image]
[image: second image]
[image: third image]
[image: fourth image]
[image: fifth image]

Why are most silhouettes, but some in color on iPhone?

Specifics of my Firefox configuration:

- Extensions enabled → CanvasBlocker, uBlock Origin, Tampermonkey (SOX).
- Custom privacy setting → Block cookies from unvisited sites, Tracking content in all windows, Cryptominers, Fingerprinters, and always send "Do Not Track" to sites.
- Disabling those extensions produces the same result.

iPhone configuration:

- Block Pop-ups is enabled.
- Firefox Focus Extensions is enabled.
- Prevent Cross-Site Tracking is enabled.
- Hide IP Address from Trackers is enabled.
- Fraudulent Website Warning is enabled.
- Privacy Preserving Ad Measurement is enabled.
- JavaScript is enabled.

I'll be happy to answer and update with more information if it can't be reproduced.

Comment: Do you think I could keep the premise and remove the humor? Well, actually, do you think the humor improves or diminish

Comment: I'd just leave it as is. Downvotes on meta aren't the same as anywhere else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to sign in separately on that page, top right.  Your picture doesn't go right to the top of the page so I can't tell, but as it does require its own login, even if you're generally logged into other parts of SE, that's the most logical explanation..

[image]

The ones then in colour are, of course, the ones you've achieved so far.

I've also had 'fun' with all my blockers & was just writing a long question on here about not being able to get the Cookies hat… then I got it. I still don't know what juggling it took. I don't think any of those blockers will prevent your personal list of hats from showing.

You have 27 hats, network-wide, btw. 3rd in the overall stats. pretty good going. I'm 10th… a few behind you ;)

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason it didn't follow along like other stack exchange sites? Due to the domain change?

Comment: Possibly. I'm not really sure, but whilst I was messing around trying to get my Cookies hat, i did a lot of logging in & out & re-launching the browser. I always find that logging to one site usually sets them all up, though occasionally a second site will also ask me to login. Every time, that particular page wanted a separate login.